# R version 4.0.3: Function For calculating Means of certain column values in R returns NaN when a row filtering argument is set to 1:278 and lower

Tags: r

I have written a function which is meant to extract the means of particle quantities in the air. However the code works perfectly, if the Id argument is defined to be anything bellow "1:279" the function results in NaN.

```
Pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) 
{
Airpoll <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>%
   lapply(read.csv) %>%
   bind_rows
Sig_data <- Airpoll[id, pollutant]
mean(Sig_data, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: That's a strange issue. Restart R and try again.